# Infopath repeating table - get field from current row

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, infopath

I have a repeating table in Infopath.  On a field change event, I need to execute a calculation to with data in the row in question.  How do I go about this in the code-behind (C#) and Xpath?

For example, I have a start date and end date.  In the code-behind the do a calculation to calculate the number of hours in the span.  This works for the first row, but not subsequent rows.  I know the way I wrote it so far only works for the first row, but how do I make this work for all rows?

Comment: Alternatively (if you don't want to resort to code behind) you can do a primitive date diff with string parsing on the fields. Then you can just use the built in rules (which keep track of repeating rows for you). If you are stuck with code behind, or already have code elsewhere, then just use XPathNodeIterator as given in one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPathNodeIterator for this. For example:
You can use XPathNodeIterator for this. For example:

```
        XPathNodeIterator nodes = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().Select("/my:myFields/my:group1/my:group2", this.NamespaceManager);

        string field1 = string.Empty;
        string field2 = string.Empty;
        string field3 = string.Empty;

        foreach (XPathNavigator node in nodes)
        {
            field1 = node.SelectSingleNode("my:field1", this.NamespaceManager).Value;
            field2 = node.SelectSingleNode("my:field2", this.NamespaceManager).Value;
            field3 = node.SelectSingleNode("my:field3", this.NamespaceManager).Value;
        }
```

This will get the value of each field and set a string variable to that value. If you wish to concatenate all the values, you'll need to modify this --  you can do something very simple like:

```
field1 = node.SelectSingleNode("my:field1", this.NamespaceManager).Value + " " + field1;
```