# loop through infopath 2010 repeating section and display data in reverse order using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have a form created in InfoPath 2010 with c# code behind.  The purpose of this form is to be a running log for issues we deal with here.  The C# is being used to generate a very specifically formatted email.  The body of this email needs to show the items from the repeating field in reverse order (newest on top).  My first issues were trying to find a way to get the data from the repeating sections to be populated to the email body at all.  I was finally able to find this foreach loop that successfully printed the data in standard order.

```
foreach (XPathNavigator node in runningLogTable)
{
    logEntry = node.SelectSingleNode("@my:entry", this.NamespaceManager).Value;
    logTime = node.SelectSingleNode("my:CurrentTime", this.NamespaceManager).Value;
    sb.Append(convertTime(logTime) + "\n");
    sb.Append(logEntry + "\n\n");
}
```

Source: [Infopath repeating table - get field from current row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477723/infopath-repeating-table-get-field-from-current-row)

Incidentally, this loop is inside of a stringBuilder function.  My question is, how do I do this in reverse order?
I've been Googling this for days and I don't know if I just don't know the correct terminology or what, but needless to say, I have been unable to locate a solution that works.  I know there has got to be a simple solution that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: OK, not sure what happened. There were a few responses, I refreshed and they were gone?  Did I get modded?

Answer (score 0):

not sure why this question dropped off the grid, but there were a few people helping me (Save, specifically)  who led me down a different path.  I was able to get my code working using the following:

```
            //Lets get those log entries!
        List<string> logEntries = new List<string>(); // Create a list array to hold each entry
        List<string> logTimes = new List<string>(); // Create a list array to hold each log time

        foreach (XPathNavigator entry in runningLogTable) // iterate through the repeating section of the log
        {
            logEntry = entry.SelectSingleNode("@my:entry", this.NamespaceManager).Value; // Get the string value from each field
            logTime = entry.SelectSingleNode("my:CurrentTime", this.NamespaceManager).Value; // Get the string value for the time from each field.
            logEntries.Add(logEntry); // Add each log entry to the list starting at position (index) 0
            logTimes.Add(convertTime(logTime)); // Add each time entry to the list starting at position (index) 0
            // Each log entry should align with the correct time entry since both start at index 0.
        }
        for (int i = (logEntries.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--) // get the count of the log entries list and loop through each indexed position in reverse.
        {
            sb.Append(logTimes[i].ToString() + "\n"); // append each indexed entry to the log starting from the last position and moving to the first (0)
            sb.Append(logEntries[i].ToString() + "\n\n"); // append each indexed time to the log starting from the last position and moving to the first (0)
        }
```

Thanks to everyone that helped.  I wish I could link to a username because **Save** really did save me!

Thanks all!!